# Faces won't fill

Tags: faces

I am a noob at 3D-modeling so I don't know if I'm just being an idiot, but I am trying to fill in a simple triangle with a face and it won't do it. It works on some triangles in the model, but not all of them. I have tried using both alt-F and F, I checked to see if there were doubles, and I tried splitting up the triangle. It just kept saying no faces filled. I'm really confused, do I just have a faulty copy of Blender?

Comment: hello, could you please share your triangle? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: pls add some picture,it will do good help.